# Java JNI trouble

Tags: java, path, java-native-interface

I have the .java, .class, .cpp, .h files: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/section2.html

After reading TotalFrickinRockstarFromMars's comment, I *tried* setting up classpath.

What's wrong?

[image: lala]
Sample1.dll IS there.

Text version:

F:\workspace\JavaJNIProj\src>java Sample1

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: F:\workspace\JavaJNIProj\src\Sample1.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
      at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
      at Sample1.main(Sample1.java:10)
```

Comment: My first reaction is that you don't have the proper classpath set up. What's your classpath?

Comment: you should take out the last exception and put that in there. I don't know JNI stuff, so I'm afraid I can't help you with that, but someone else might and they might miss it if it's just in a comment. Good luck with it :-)

Comment: Did you try to set the -Djava.library.path to the directory that contains your .dll ?

Comment: Please copy the error message as text instead of making a screenshot. (You should be able to mark it with the mouse.) This makes it (1) better readable and (2) searchable.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann I tried. The resulted formatting is horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you miss some dependency DLLs. You can download DependencyWalker http://www.dependencywalker.com/

This supposed to help you to find it.